# How to get the varible by using contract address

Tags: solidity

I am a solidity beginner of Remix-IDE  and deployed the following contract to BSC testnet at address  0x..................

```
contract MyContract {
    uint256 public lastRun = 1;

    function setv(uint256 vv) public {
            lastRun = vv;
    }
}
```

For using the function and varible at MyContract,
I hope to use the contract like followngs

```
interface MyInterface {
    function setv(uint256 vv) external;
}


contract MyNewContract {
    address Myaddr = 0x..................;

    function rr(uint256 vv) public
    {
        MyInterface(Myaddr).setv(vv);
    }
}
```

For function setv at MyContract, it works.
My question is how to get the varible lastRun from MyContract directly
at MyNewContract.

Answer (score 0):

Every `public` variable generates automatically a getter function with the same name (even if it's not visible in the code). Therefore you can add it to the interface and call it. Something like this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    function setv(uint256 vv) external;
    function lastRun() returns (uint256) public;
}


contract MyNewContract {
    address Myaddr = 0x..................;

    function rr(uint256 vv) public
    {
        MyInterface(Myaddr).setv(vv);
        uint256 val = MyInterface(Myaddr).lastRun();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I have tried it, but there are some compilation error:

SyntaxError: No visibility specified. Did you intend to add "external"?
--> contracts/vv.sol:6:5:
|
6 | function lastRun() returns (uint256);
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

TypeError: Functions in interfaces must be declared external.
--> contracts/vv.sol:6:5:
|
6 | function lastRun() returns (uint256);
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Sorry, after add external to interface, it works.
thank you very much